# AJAX update delete tr in table : backend works but glitch with frontend

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, dom

The purpose of the script below is to allow users to post new updates and to delete them without the page refreshing : that's why i'm using AJAX.

There are 2 glitches:

- when a user posts an update, it's correctly saved in the DB, and the correct update slides down in my table but when i look at the source code, i can see the wrong postid is echoed  (it's always the postid from a couple rows below in the DB).
- when a user deletes a post, nothing happens on the frontend: tr doesn't slide up BUT the row does get deleted correctly in the DB.

PHP part :

```
echo "<table id=\"update_list\">
    <tr class=\"cell$postid\">
          <td>$post

      <div id=\"delete\">
          <span class=\"delete_update\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"$postid;\">X</a></span>  
          </div>  
          <hr>    
          </td>
    </tr>
  </table>";
```

AJAX part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $("#addpost_button").click(function() 
        {
            var element = $(this);
            var boxval = $("#status").val(); // #status is the ID of the input where the users type in updates 
            var dataString = 'post='+ boxval;
            if(boxval=='')
            {
                alert("Please Enter Some Text");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#flash").show();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update_post.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){

                        $("#cell").prepend(html);
                        $("#update_list tr:first").slideDown("slow");
                        document.getElementById('post').value='';
                        $("#flash").hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

    $('.delete_update').live("click",function() 
        {
            var ID = $(this).attr("id");
            var dataString = 'postid='+ ID;
            if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this post? "))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete_post.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $(".cell"+ ID).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

EDIT:
Code from update_post.php:

```
<?php
include "includes/config.php";
if(isset($_POST['post']))


$table=query("INSERT INTO postlist (id, postid, post) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",         
$_SESSION["id"], '', $_POST["post"]);
$table = query("SELECT post, postid FROM postlist WHERE id = ? ORDER BY postid DESC",   
$_SESSION["id"]);

foreach ($table as $row){
   $post=$_POST['post'];
   $postid = $row["postid"];



echo "<table id=\"update_list\">
<tr class=\"cell$postid\">
  <td>$post

    <div id=\"delete\">
    <span class=\"delete_update\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"$postid;\">X</a></span>  
    </div>  
  <hr>    
  </td>
</tr>
</table>";     
} 
?>
```

Comment: for your first problem, we need to see the backend php code of update_post.php to be able to debug properly

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't animate table rows. You could animate the contents and then remove the row though.

Comment: I don't see how you can be deleting the correct row, since your assignment to `ID` is wrong. It should be `$(this).find("a").attr("id")`.

Comment: There are some general problems with your uses of classes and IDs. Every row duplicates `id="delete"`, but IDs have to be unique. Meanwhile, you're using unique `class="cell$postid"` -- if they're unique, you should use IDs, classes are for when you want to operate on a bunch of similar elements.

Comment: You have syntax error at foreach($table as $row) ;  shouldnt it be {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to repalce

```
 <span class=\"delete_update\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"$postid;\">X</a></span>
```

to

```
 <span class=\"delete_update\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"$postid\">X</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This mightve just been a simple formatting mistake when you were posting to stack overflow...but this part should be...

```
foreach ($table as $row){
  $post= $row['post'];
  $postid = $row["postid"];
  ...rest of code  
}
```

Not...

```
 foreach ($table as $row);
  $post= $_POST['post'];
  $postid = $row["postid"];

{
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, i made a mistake when i copy pasted my code !

Comment: Your $_POST['post'], shouldn't that be $row['post']? to make sure you're echoing the correct post from the database, not the posted post